# iAd Admob mediation beginner

Tags: ios, admob, iad, mediator

So i've integrated iAd banner but I haven't signed their ad network agreement yet. On my app, the iAd banner says "You're connected to iAd, learn more", while the Google AdMob banner I only have a test banner. The AdMob test banner always plays over the iAd banner in ViewDidLoad, iAd banner never even shows. I don't know where to start with the whole mediation thing? Do I sign up with iAd network first or do I just start the mediation on Apple's side or do I do the mediation on Google's side? I don't even know where to start? Can someone who's done iAd Admob mediation just point me in the right direction where to begin because i've been looking on this site and i'm confused?

Answer (score 0):

iAd and AdMob are two different ad networks. I haven't worked with iAd yet, so I can't help much there but to offer that it sounds like you're using the test as unit code.

As far as AdMob, I can that you're like using the test ad unit ID. You must use this ID when developing your app, and when you deploy to production and deploy your app you switch the ad Unit ID to the one you made for your app (mandated by the ToU).

You should adjust your layout to provide spacing between the ads so that they are not overlapping. Without looking at you're code can't help beyond a recommendation to review the implementation docs for each ad service.